# Space to allocate before sprintf

Tags: c, memory-management

I just finished chasing a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) that was entirely my fault. I'd like to avoid it happening again.

I have a function which formats a date to a certain preset format. Turns out I was not allocating enough space:

```
char* FormatDate(DT dateTime)
{
    char* formattedDate;
    formattedDate = (char*)malloc(
      6 //That was my bug, I had 5. For the record, I forgot a comma, not the terminal null...
      + numlen(dateTime.Year)
      + numlen(dateTime.Month)
      + numlen(dateTime.Day)
      + numlen(dateTime.Hour)
      + numlen(dateTime.Minute)
      + numlen(dateTime.Second)
      );
      sprintf(formattedDate,"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second);
    return formattedDate;
}
```

`numlen` calculates the number of characters the number would take if printed in "%d" format.

And yes, the calling function has the duty to free the response.

What I'd like to know is how to avoid having the hardcoded `6`, which arguably could change. `sprintf` does return the numbers of characters written, but that's a lot like the chicken and the egg... Is there another approach with pre-allocating that's safe? And not, say allocate a space of 250 just to make sure anything fits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that if have access to the standard library version of snprintf you can do this:

```
char* FormatDate(DT dateTime)
{
      size_t needed = snprintf(NULL, 0,"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second);
      char* formattedDate = (char*)malloc(needed);
      snprintf(formattedDate, needed,"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second);
      return formattedDate;
}
```

Original source obtained from StackOverflow

```
char* get_error_message(char const *msg) {
    size_t needed = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s: %s (%d)", msg, strerror(errno), errno);
    char  *buffer = malloc(needed);
    snprintf(buffer, needed, "%s: %s (%d)", msg, strerror(errno), errno);
    return buffer;
}
```

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775403/using-snprintf-to-avoid-buffer-overruns but duplicated to make finding answers quicker.

Comment: Shouldn't you allocate `needed+1`? I'm using Visual Studio 2005, it doesn't think it has `snprintf`. It does have sprintf, though. I like the approach of sending it to null. I think I'll go with that (if `sprintf` supports it).

Comment: If I remember that version of MSVC has _snprintf and it works differently than the standard library version.

Comment: Yup, found `_snprintf`. Works, but I don't know what's different.

Comment: I cannot say for sure it is, but I remember reading it would sometimes not null terminate. If your tests pass then no worries.

Comment: That's not reassuring.